# Planning NAO to grasp object from floor with moveit

Tags: ros, moveit, move-group, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to take object from floor with nao. Can I create such move group where are both legs and one of the arms, so that moveit plans robot to squat and then moving arm near object?
Or do I have to create multiple move groups and then "manually" plan squat and after that plan moving arm to the object?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200725/planning-nao-to-grasp-object-from-floor-with-moveit/) by [siim](https://answers.ros.org/users/21343/siim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Sure you can do it, for now there is only one group for each kinematic chain but you can add groups in the srdf file in the config folder.

There are some examples of complete body motion planning for other robots. (here HRP2 https://github.com/davetcoleman/moveit_hrp2/blob/master/hrp2jsknt_moveit_config/config/HRP2JSKNT.srdf)

You could do it with multiple move groups but it will certainly take you a lot more time.

Hope this helps,

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2015-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1